# Django Count lines in a Subquery

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

I need to count lines in a subquery and here is my solution for sqlite.

```
class SQCount(Subquery):
    """Count lines in subquery"""
    template = "(SELECT count(*) FROM (%(subquery)s) _count)"
    output_field = models.IntegerField() 

sub = MyModel.objects.filter(user=OuterRef(OuterRef('id'))).values('id')
qs = qs.annotate(count_total=SQCount(sub))
```

It works great for sqlite but not for MySQL (complains about Unknown column in 'where' clause). Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why is `user` not a `ForeignKey` to `MyModel`? That would make it more elegant in Django and (likely) more efficient at the database side.

Comment: `user` is a ForeignKey to `MyModel`. But I'd like to use subquery here because in reality my requests have to use subqueries (in question you can see simplified code)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the right way to count lines in subquery in Django

```
subquery = Subquery(
    Child.objects.filter(
        parent_id=OuterRef('id')
    )
    .order_by()
    ).values(
        'parent'
    ).annotate(
        count=Count('pk')
    ).values(
        'count'
    ), 
    output_field=IntegerField(),
)
Parent.objects.annotate(child_count=Coalesce(subquery, 0))
```

- The `.order_by()` will cancel ordering if any
- First values `.values('parent')` will introduce right grouping
- `.annotate(count=Count('pk'))` Will annotate (ad to each line) the answer we're looking for
- Second values `.values('count')` will limit rows to the `count` exclusively
- `Coalesce` will return first not null value or zero

That is tricky to do from Django but pretty efficient.

Comment: The django-sql-utils library removes a lot of the boiler plate so that it's not so tricky
Parent.objects.annotate(child_count=SubqueryCount('child'))